# Code Coverage for MonoDevelop Unity version on Mac OSX

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, code-coverage, monodevelop, osx-yosemite

So here is the context :

> - I'm testing an application with NUnit on MonoDevelop (the Unity Version).
> - **I do not use UnityTestTools.**
> - I'm working in C#

My problem :

> I'm looking for a solution to get my code coverage. I actually heard about MonoCov but i have no idea how to install it on my OSX.
> I also search for this options in MonoDevelop and i kept a look at some post on StackOverFlow but no i didn't find any solution for my particular case.

So does anyone has a solution ?

Comment: We don't use 'Thanks' and 'Hi' or signatures on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

**Depends upon which version of Mono is *actually* running the tests**:

i.e. Which Mono version is running your nunit tests, if using the nunit embedded via MonoDevelop, thus you are using the Mono that is running MonoDevelop. If your tests are shelling out to mono or loading a separate app domain, which mono is used for unit-runner/console, etc...

Why? Older versions (3.x) include the internal cov profiler, but in newer versions this has been **replaced** by the code coverage filter.

To use the older monocov profiler you add the mono option "--profile=monocov" when 'debug' running your program.exe (via nunit runner, cmdline, etc..). This will generate a "program.exe.cov" file that can be loaded in the MonoCov gui.

Newer mono versions use the profiler coverage filter "--profile=log:coverage" that produces output like the following and does not have a gui like MonoCov, it produces plain text:

```
Coverage Summary:
    xCorFlags (/Users/administrator/code/corflags/xCorFlags.exe) 26% covered (42 methods - 11 covered)
        <Module> ?% covered (0 methods - 1 covered)
        CorFlags.CorFlagsSettings 25% covered (4 methods - 1 covered)
        CorFlags.MainClass 50% covered (2 methods - 1 covered)
        CorFlags.CommandLineParser 40% covered (20 methods - 8 covered)
```

Disclaimer: That is from my own blog [post](http://sushihangover.github.io/mono-code-coverage-using-the-new-coverage-filter/)

If you are using an older version of Mono (due to Unity?, which version are they using now?), then the movcov profiler 'should' work and produce the .cov files. At that point you just need the MonoCov Gui that can be built from source (update the following to match your OS-X env):

```
# Clone the MonoCov repo
git clone https://github.com/mono/monocov.git MonoCov
cd MonoCov
# A really old version of cecil and it not available as a nuget
curl http://go-mono.com/archive/cecil/cecil-0.6-bin.zip -o cecil-0.6-bin.zip
unzip cecil-0.6-bin.zip
# Make sure configure can find the Mono.Option source file
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export 
# Config to install to users home dir
/configure --cecil=$PWD/monocov/cecil-0.6/Mono.Cecil.dll --prefix $HOME/monocov
# Fix Makefile, gmcs no longer exists under Mono 4.x and Makefile is hard coded
sed -i.bak s/gmcs/mcs/g Makefile
# Pass -m32 to make since OS-X Mono framework is still 32-bit
CC="cc -m32" make
# Install does not properly create bin dir, do it before the first install
mkdir $HOME/monocov/bin
# Install..
make install
```

Disclaimer: This is from another blog post of [mine](http://sushihangover.github.io/monocov-building-on-os-x/).

Comment: Thx for your answer,

i actually helped me a little but i'm still blocked.
After installing monocov, in the right directory i try to use this command :

`MONO_OPTIONS="--profile=monocov" nunit-console2 Assembly-CSharp.dll`  but i have this error that appears :


"The 'monocov' profiler wasn't found in the main executable nor could it be loaded from 'mono-profiler-monocov'.".

I looked into my monoDevelop directory and i have the libmono-profiler-monocov.so file but i guess i needs the .dylib file and i can't find it. I'm using MonoDevelop 4.0.1

Comment: Which version of mono is that? mono --version : And you can look at setting the DYLIB path before running unit console : http://sushihangover.github.io/mono-unable-to-find-the-ldylib-native-library/

Comment: Here is what mono --version returns :

Mono JIT compiler version 3.12.1 (tarball Sun Jul  5 10:37:00 PDT 2015)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           normal
 SIGSEGV:       normal
 Notification:  kqueue
 Architecture:  amd64
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            sgen

Comment: "Architecture: amd64" 64bit build, so check the "libmono-profiler-monocov.so" that you have if it is 32 or 64 bit... just use 'file' on it